# VSCode + maven project wrong java version

Tags: maven, visual-studio-code

JAVA_HOME:

```
PS C:\Users\Himanshu\Desktop\work\demo> $Env:JAVA_HOME
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.1
```

[Java version mismatch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pe2EB.png)

Please see the above image. Why is it displaying Java 1.6 and in brackets pointing to java 17 ?
This is also not compiling lambda functions.

Looks like a bug in VSCode.

**EDIT: I switched to Intellij Idea. And it worked smoothly. It is using the JAVA_HOME. :)**

**EDIT2: As asked in the comments**

```
PS C:\Windows\System32> (Get-Command java.exe).Path
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe

PS C:\Windows\System32> java --version
java 17.0.1 2021-10-19 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17.0.1+12-LTS-39)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.1+12-LTS-39, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl+Shift+P</kbd>, type (with auto-completion): "Java: Configure Runtime" (per project;)

[image: VS Code screenshot]

---

When "editing java version" (the pen symbol next to 17), I get redirected to pom.xml>project>properties>java.version (in this particular project):

```xml
 <properties>
    ...
    <java.version>17</java.version>
    ...
 </properties>
```

---

When, I delete/comment the `<java.version>` (java.version works only in poms, which mapped it (explicitly, like spring-booot-parent, in my example)) to:

```xml
  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
```

([Ref](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html))

---

... the maven default (when omitting these properties/not configuring compiler-plugin) is: **1.5**!!!

Which results in (my VS Code to) the "closest matching" Execution Environment (in my case "JavaSE-1.8"):

[image: Fallback to "closest (java)execution environment"]

---

..., which is configured in "Settings>Extensions>Java>Configuration>Runtimes (edit in settings.json)", like:

```json
...
   "java.configuration.runtimes": [        
        {
            "name": "JavaSE-1.8",
            "path": "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_311"
        },
        {
            "name": "JavaSE-11",
            "path": "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-11.0.12"
        },
        {
            "name": "JavaSE-16",
            "path": "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-16.0.2"
        },
        {
            "name": "JavaSE-17",
            "path": "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-17"
        }
    ],
...
```

- Bringing consistence in these settings
- updating to latest JDK (minor) updates
- and: **Having distinct java.exe in %PATH%**! (consistent with `JAVA_HOME`)

should solve our "Java Runtime Problems" (with the [Official Java Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-pack)).

---

But please keep in mind, that **other extension** (can) have custom "java runtime/jdk" configuration. I currently think of:

- sonarlint
- gradle

(Settings>Search Settings>"java...")

Comment: Java version listed on this page is 1.6 but in bracket it points to version 17. See the image in my question.

Comment: In the (new!?) screenshot it is not "java version" it is "language (downward compatibility) level".

Comment: This is so confusing. Why can't it detect JAVA_HOME and use that everywhere ? Why it is showing 1.6 ? Why it is not able to compile lambda even when JAVA_HOME points to jdk17 ?

Intellij idea setup was so smooth.

Comment: maybe it is not only `JAVA_HOME` to blame, but also: The "order" in `%PATH%`...please try in pswh: `(get-command java.exe).Path` also `java --version` in git bash: `which java`

Comment: `JAVA_HOME` is important for maven|gradle, but i "assume" vs code relies on: 1. config, 2. falls back to default (1st run)/%PATH%

Comment: see update, @Himanshu ! :-)

Comment: Adding "java.configuration.runtimes" in settings worked. Thanks! But it is still disappointing having to add extra configuration. 

I think the following happened:
(1) JAVA_HOME points to jdk17.0.1 
(2) pom.xml either expected jdk17 or the default jdk1.6 (in my system).
(3) VSCode was not able to find either of them (jdk17 or jdk1.6). So it complained.
(4) I tried setting version to 17.0.1 in pom.xml. It worked once. But then I accidentally deleted cache and everything broke again. :(

Comment: "pswh: (get-command java.exe).Path also java --version in git bash: which java"

Comment: Please see EDIT2 in the question. I don't have git installed.